# Why is the transpose so useful?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, applications, dual-spaces

I am learning linear algebra using the textbook  *Linear Algebra Done Right*, trying to understand the subject through a logical, pure math perspective. I'm, simultaneously, learning applied linear algebra in college, and trying to reconcile the two. Specifically, I am very confused on why dual spaces become used so often in the form of the transpose.

Let me explain. My understanding of the transpose from *Linear Algebra Done Right* is as follows:

Define on each vector space $V$ another vector space denoted $V^{*}$ which is the space of all linear functional on that space. I.e. it is the space of linear maps from $V$ to $F$, the field of interest.

Intuitively, I understand the dual space of a vector space as the space of all possible weight-assignments to the vectors of a vector space. Each element $f \in V^{*}$ is analogous to a measuring device that assigns particular weights to every vector.

Then by the dual map of a linear map, $T^{*}$, I understand a way of defining a particular measuring device in the domain that agrees with the measures of the co-domain. Let me rephrase this using notation:

Suppose $T: V \rightarrow W$. Then $T^{*}: W^{*} \rightarrow V^{*}$ is defined such that $T^{*}(g)(x) = g(T(x))$.

In other words, $T^{*}$ defines a weight-assignment in $V^{*}$ of the pre-image of $T$ that agrees with the $W^{*}$ weight-assignment of the image of $T$.

...

Now this is all good, but where I become confused in why this would have so many applications. For example:

1. How should I think of the least-square solution method, where we solve for $T^{*}T(x) = T^{*}(b)$? What is this statement really saying, aside from being a purely computational trick for finding the least square solution. I.e. why does this work on a deeper level?
2. The projection matrix is given by $A(A^{*}A)^{-1}A^{*}$. Why must this be so, in the context of dual spaces.

More generally, why does the tranpose come up so often as a computational trick to simplify problems? On the face of it, I am having a hard time seeing how the formal definition leads to the practical uses.

Comment: $A^*$ is actually the adjoint of $A$

Comment: Am I just making a notational mistake, or is my definition the definition of the adjoin?

Comment: If you are working over $\mathbb R^n$, then the matrices are the same. However, in $\mathbb C^n$, the adjoint is the conjugate transpose. I think it should be covered in chapter 8(?) of your book

Comment: I think it would be helpful for you to read some more geometric proofs of the result in question. Axler is a functional analyst and his book does not give a very good geometric intuition for what is going on at all.

Comment: @AnotherPerson Do you have a good recommendation on books to develop some geometric intuition of the topic?

Comment: Alexander Givental's linear algebra book.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give an answer to a confused question, so, this is a long comment. Firstly let's use slightly different notation.

Transpose of a linear map $T: V \to W$ is an induced pull-back of linear functionals $g \in W^*$ and let's denote it as $T^t: W^* \to V^*.$

If there is also an inner product on $V$, we can define  adjoint of a linear operator $T: V \to V$ as $T^{*}:V \to V$:
$\langle T^{*}x,y\rangle=\langle x,Ty\rangle$

Both of your projection-related applications assume inner product and use the adjoint $T^{*}$ (or its matrix $A^{*}$)

One might ask how and why the (matrix representations of) transpose and adjoint are related (can they be equal!?) It has been asked before, for example: [Relationship between Definition of Adjoint of a Linear Operator and the Transpose of Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362774/relationship-between-definition-of-adjoint-of-a-linear-operator-and-the-transpos)

Sorry if this only begins to answer your question(s) by hopefully clearing the confusion